# INDEX con Cassandra ¿Cómo hacer este query?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Estoy desarrollando un problema de Cassandra a modo de práctica, sin embargo, no sé cómo solucionar el siguiente query:

> Q1: Dado el número de pasaporte del ciudadano, listar todos los pasaportes que le corresponden.

Es decir, tengo una entidad de ciudadano y otra de pasaporte, con una relación de 1 a muchos.

La tabla que he diseñado para eso es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE citizen ( 
 citizen_id int, 
 passport_id text, 
 date date, 
 nationality text, 
 PRIMARY KEY ((passport_id, citizen_id), date) 
);
```

Sé que sería muy sencillo en MySQL (Un JOIN lo resolvería), pero soy novata en Cassandra y no sé si con un index funcionaría. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias.

Comment: La sintaxis mostrada es CQL, no SQL. Muy similar pero no igual

Answer (score 0):

Puede cambiar la estructura de la tabla para evitar el uso de la clave de partición compuesta. Algo como esto:

```
CREATE TABLE citizen ( 
 citizen_id int, 
 passport_id text, 
 date date, 
 nationality text, 
 PRIMARY KEY ((passport_id, citizen_id), date) 
);
```

en este caso manejará ambas consultas: dame los datos del pasaporte para cititzen y pasaporte dados (`select * from citizen where citizen_id = ... and passport_id = ...`) o dame todos los pasaportes para un ciudadano dado (`select * from citizen where citizen_id = ..`). Ni siquiera estoy seguro de que necesite tener una `date` como columna de agrupación ...

P.S. Lo sentimos, traducido a través de Google

Comment: Yes, you are right! However, I'm asked to query ONLY by passport_id, not citizen_id.

Comment: sorry - looks like google translate didn't translate correctly. with current design you can't easily do it - you need to do a full scan, for example, using Spark. Or you can change table structure to have only passpord_id as partition key, and having an additional column to keep all "additional passports" in for given person. Btw, you can ask questions about Cassandra in Spanish at https://community.datastax.com/spaces/91/index.html